# Get the difference between current column and previous column

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a dataframe like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 15, 6), c = c(7, 8, 19))


  a  b  c
1 1  4  7
2 2 15  8
3 3  6 19
```

And I want to replace each column with the difference between that column and the previous one (while leaving the first column as is):

```
   a  b  c
1  1  3  3
2  2 13 -7
3  3  3 13
```

I managed to do it, but it seems quite ugly:

```
df2 = df %>% t %>% as.data.frame %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ . - lag(.))) %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(a = df$a)
```

In Python you can specify an `axis` option that tells `lag` to lag rows or columns, but I don't find anything like that in R. Is there a better way to perform what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `diff` after transposing the dataframe:

```
cbind(df[1], t(diff(t(df))))

  a  b  c
1 1  3  3
2 2 13 -7
3 3  3 13
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it as a single subtraction:

```
df - cbind(0, df[-length(df)])
#  a  b  c
#1 1  3  3
#2 2 13 -7
#3 3  3 13
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach using `rowwise` and `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarize(a, d = list(diff(c_across(everything())))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(d, names_sep="", names_repair=\(x) letters[1:3])
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     3
2     2    13    -7
3     3     3    13
```

Answer (score 1):

Using no packages :

```
data.frame(df$a,t(diff(t(df))))
```

It yields:

```
  df.a  b  c
1    1  3  3
2    2 13 -7
3    3  3 13
```

`diff` calculates the difference between cells, `t()` transposes the result to have it in the right format, and `data.frame()` binds it to the first column `a` again. You will probably want to rename the first column (named `df.a` here).

Comment: `diff` is a vectorised function which will calculate row-to-row differences, so you don't have to apply it across each row using `apply` - `cbind(df[1], t(diff(t(df))))`

Comment: @thelatemail noted, thank you ! I used apply right away and noticed I could use it on both rows and columns so I didnt assume that. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
> df[-1] <- df[-1] - df[-length(df)]

> df
  a  b  c
1 1  3  3
2 2 13 -7
3 3  3 13
```